# Как узнать, зарегестрирована ли схеме диплинка на устройтве?

Tags: java, unity3d, manifest

я использую диплинк для запуска юнити приложения.
В манифесте добавлен такой intent-filter -

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="xx.yyyyy.zzz" />
```

Для поиска вызываю queryIntentActivities с таким интентом -

```
intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", "android.intent.action.VIEW", new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri").CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "https://xx.yyyyy.zzz"));
```

Если в манифесте есть мой intent-filter, то queryIntentActivities его находит, как изменить интент для того, что бы я мог найти мой апп из другого приложения, запущенного на том же телефоне ?
Спасибо.